# Popup not going away after setting a new account

Tags: macbook-pro

I have set up my child's account on my MacBook but the following pop-up isn't going away. I gave my(admin) password and tried with a standard(logged-in account) password but the pop-up won't go away. why? It is very annoying[image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WNTAN.png)

Comment: Whose account is this and which password are you entering, yours or your child's?

Comment: sorry I might missed that it was my child account and I tried using both my(admin) and his(standard user) password.

Comment: Maybe try restarting the mac, or maybe cancelling it? ( i get this popup many times as well, and even after entering the password once, i keep getting it again, so now i just cancel it)

Comment: Could it be that Creative Cloud isn't finding the password it is looking for in the Keychain? Does the child account even need Creative Cloud?

Answer (score 0):

This is likely due to corruption of the Keychain cache.

The first thing I would try is the following:

1. **Launch Terminal** (If you're not familiar with Terminal, go to **Finder**, click on the **Go** menu and select the **Utilities** option. Then double-click on **Terminal** from the Finder window that appears.)
2. After Terminal opens, enter the following command (or copy and paste it):

   `cd ~/Library/Keychains`
3. Press <kbd>return</kbd>
4. Enter `ls` and press <kbd>return</kbd> again
5. The amount of data appearing on your screen will depend on how much is in your keychain
6. Take a note of the string that appeared immediately after you entered the `ls` command
7. It will look **something like this**:

   `070CB08F-385G-519B-8FB2-FC21F5CFD4FD`

(Note: If you have a lot of data you may need to scroll up to see the string.)

8. Now type the following command in Terminal: `rm -rf` followed by the first three characters of the string that appeared for you. Using my example above, this means you'd enter `rm -rf 070`
9. Press <kbd>tab</kbd> to autopopulate the full string and then press <kbd>enter</kbd>
10. **IMPORTANT:** If at Step 6 you noticed there was more than one string appearing after the `ls` command, then you need to repeat Steps 8 - 9 for each string. So, if you had three sets of strings listed then you'd run the `rm -rf` command three times, one for each string.
11. Once complete, do a full reboot of your MacBook

Once rebooted, test to see if the issue is gone and let me know if not.

Comment: Should it run from a Standard account or an admin account?